# Observer Pattern confusion

Tags: java, oop, swing, events

If i have a GUI builder which builds my first interface and to that interface I attach an observer which detects when a certain field in that interface is updated then do I have to do one of the following;

1) create interface1 from builder and then attach an observer so as the builder can know when a certain task has completed
2) Do i just create an observer and then the observer creates the interface?

Basically i am trying to create an interface from builder, which then, on a button click goes and gets some data. When this data has been retrieved i want to let the builder class know so it can proceed to use it to build interface 2. I am trying to user the observer design pattern to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create the interface, then add (or register/attach) the relevant observers afterward. Something like (in pseudocode);

```
GUI mygui = GUIBuilder.createNewGUI();

ButtonListener OK = new OKButtonListener();
ButtonListener Cancel = new CancelButtonListener();
DataListener dataReady = new dataReadyListener();

mygui.registerButtonListener(OK);
mygui.registerButtonListener(Cancel);
mygui.registerDataListener(dataReady);

mygui.show();
```

If all the GUIs you are building will have the same listeners attached, you can have the interface builder create and attach the listeners for you as well.

Comment: sorry for the lack of understanding here, but is this all going on inside the builder class. im just worried that having listeners in the builder class breaks responsibility driven design

Comment: The XXXListener classes are the observers.  The mygui is the observable.

Comment: so we have an observer class for each control we want to monitor?

Comment: You don't necessarily need an observer for each control. For example you can have a ControlButtonListener class which handles multiple types of button presses. In this case, the interface to your listener needs to take some data passed in from the observable (the GUI) in order to know how to proceed. A simply example is passing in a string value of the button's text as data to the observer - the observer can have a switch statement checking which button was pressed (by looking at the string value), and act accordingly.

Comment: Also, you have a valid point. For the most flexible approach, your builder shouldn't create listeners on it's own. It can have method(s) that take in listeners and register them as needed... so you could have an AddButtonListener() and AddDataListener() on the builder, which will encapsulate the steps above to register them onto the appropriate parts of your GUI. Whether you do it this way or do it as shown above is a design choice left to you, based on the specifics of the application you are building.

Comment: i still have a qustion regarding this. The observer observes when something is changed and reacts after you call `setChanged()` and `notifyObservers()` but, once this change is trapped in the observer class i still cant tell the builder to build the second interface can i?

Comment: @Ricki Why wouldn't you be able to? Did you get your code working?